# Replace all word occurrences with ones from Object literal Dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a question about accessing individual parts of a JavaScript object.

```
var dictionary = {
   "gimme": "༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ",
   "umadbro": "¯\_(ツ)_/¯",
   "lenny": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"
}
```

So I'm making a program that will print the actual ascii/Uni art when you type its corresponding name (gimme, umadbro, lenny, etc.), however I'm not really sure how to go about doing that. Here's the code I have so far:

```
function checkCharacter() {
  //Assign $ascii_box variable to ascii-box element
  var $ascii_box = document.getElementById("ascii-box");

//Update value of $ascii_box_value everytime the text field changes
  $ascii_box.on("input", function() {
  var $ascii_box_value = $ascii_box.val();
});

//Check if value in text box is equal to a name in the dictionary object
  //If equal, print the emote to the screen
  if ($ascii_box_value === dictionary) {
 }
}
```

How would I be able to access the words in dictionary and have them print out as emotes when entered in the textbox? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: use `square brackets`.

Comment: also you are mixing jquery and standard dom api.

Comment: Thanks, will do! Would you be able to go into further detail about how it makes the values easier to access/modify? It's a CodePen project by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Continue typing and have fun ;)

```js
var dictionary = {
    "gimme": "༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ",
    "umadbro": "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯",
    "lenny": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"
};

var re = new RegExp( Object.keys(dictionary).join("|"), "ig");  // /gimme|umabro|lenny/ig

$("#ascii-box").on("input", function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, v){                 // Let's modify val directly:
        return v.replace(re, function(m) {      // returning a replace of it's value against our regex /gimme|umabro|lenny/ig
            return dictionary[m.toLowerCase()]; // by the lowercase match
        });
    });
}).trigger("input"); // Trigger is just for DEMO
```

```css
textarea{width:100%; height:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ascii-box">Gimme Something that you like or gimme just a Lenny please. Enter some text...</textarea>
```

Thanks to `toLowerCase()` as you can see you can also type `Lenny` uppercase, it'll still be converted into `( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ascii_box_value === dictionary
```

This compares the value of the text box to `dictionary` itself. What you need is:

```
dictionary.hasOwnProperty($ascii_box_value)
```

to see whether the key is contained in the dictionary. Then you can use

```
dictionary[$ascii_box_value]
```

to retrieve the value. This is called square bracket notation. You can use it to get a property by a string that is not hardcoded. Otherwise, you can also use dot notation.

Examples:

```
dictionary["lenny"]; // returns "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"

dictionary.umadbro; // returns "¯\_(ツ)_/¯"

var value="gimme";
dictionary[value]; // returns "༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ"
```

To complete your `if` statement:

```
//Check if value in text box is equal to a name in the dictionary object
//If equal, print the emote to the screen
if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty($ascii_box_value)) {
  document.write(dictionary[$ascii_box_value]);
}
```

Not sure where exactly you want to print it, but that’s how you’d retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value associated with the key in the dictionary is undefined, and if it is not, then print the value somewhere. Or use it in some fashion.

```js
var dictionary = {
   "gimme": "༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ",
   "umadbro": "¯\_(ツ)_/¯",
   "lenny": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"
};

$('#ascii_box').on("input", function() { 
  //check if dictionary value is not undefined
  if(dictionary[this.value] != [][0])
    //print value somewhere
    print(this.value);
  else clear();
});
function print(str){
 $("#display").text(dictionary[str]);  
}
function clear(){
 $("#display").text("");  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="ascii_box" /></div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing this could be:

```
$ascii_box.on("input", function() {
    var input = $ascii_box.val();
    var emote = dictionary[input];

    if (emote) {
        //print emote to screen?
        $(body).append(emote);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a couple people have gotten to the answer before I could have, but here's a simple jsfiddle to help you further understand what's going on.

```
var dictionary = {
"gimme": "༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ",
"umadbro": "¯\_(ツ)_/¯",
"lenny": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"
}

// use jquery to select the dom element
var $ascii_input = $("#ascii-input");

//get dictionary value when input value is entered.
$ascii_input.change(function () {
// grab whatever text is in the input field
var $ascii_input_text = $("#ascii-input").val();

// grab value based on the on the key provided and display.
$(".ascii-output").html(dictionary[$ascii_input_text]);
console.log(dictionary[$ascii_input_text]);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mannyyang/pffpeb8x/1/